# C++11 vector makes copies on rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move, rvalue-reference

I have some strange behavior on std::vector with adding rvalues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    A():i_{5}{std::cout << "default" << std::endl;}
    A(const A &data) { std::cout << "copied!" << std::endl; }
    A(A &&data) {      std::cout << "moved " << std::endl; }
    int i_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<A> datavec;
    datavec.push_back(A{});
    datavec.push_back(A{});
    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
default
moved 
default
moved 
copied!
```

So vector still creates copies of A, the more pushes I do - the more copies I get.
However, if I replace move constructor with default one **A(A &&data) = default;** or delete copy constructor with **A(const A &data) = delete;** I get right result where no copies are made. I also have no copies if I first call datavec.reserve with enough size.
I use gcc version 5.4.0 with no specific arguments

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main ../main.cpp
```

Have you got any thoughts on why vector makes copies of obvious rvalues? I hope it is not some bug of STL

Comment: Great question, great answer, and great duplicate spot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `std::vector` is copying your elements during *internal buffer reallocation*. It is choosing to copy instead of moving because your move constructor is not marked `noexcept`. Marking it...

```
A(A &&) noexcept {      std::cout << "moved " << std::endl; }
```

...will fix the issue.

Telling the compiler that your *move constructor* will not throw allows `std::vector`'s implementation to move during internal reallocation, fulfilling the *exception guarantees* demanded by the C++ Standard.

Alternatively, you can `std::vector::reserve` your container in advance to prevent the growth of the internal buffer.